# A Sharepoint 2013 ECB (Edit Control Block) menu position issue with IE 11

Tags: sharepoint-designer, ecb-menu, ie

You cannot vote on your own post 
0

I have an ECB menu popup in SharePoint 2013. It works well in other browsers, but in IE it appears too far UP from a parent dialog when clicking on the ellipsis (...) as following pic.
[image]
I tried to zoom the IE browser to 110% or to resize the IE browser then the ECB menu is also working well. The problem is the Callout.js calculates the TOP property of the the ECB menu position incorrectly.

The ECB menu is working well with other browsers as the following pics.
[image]

Please help us to address how to fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This often occurs due to the browser using IE Enterprise Mode (or otherwise forced to a pre-IE9 rendering mode). EM isn't supported with SharePoint 2013/2016.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what can I do with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I thought I answered that. Disable IE Enterprise Mode.

Comment: Thanks, I did but the issue is still there!